# What is the minimum supporting android api level for Google Text to Speech and Samsung Tex to Speech engines?

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech, android-speech-api

I am using Text to Speech feature in my Android application.

Here I am using Google Text to Speech, Samsung Tex to Speech engines. But I do not have idea from which version (api level) of android OS is supported by Google Text to Speech, Samsung Tex to Speech engines.

I have gone through the play store information but I find the field "Requires Android" is Varies with device. It will not help for me.
If any of my application user is facing the problem with Text to Speech I can give the the information about the supporting version of TTS engine.

I need to know what is the minimum supporting android version (or API level) for:

- Google Text to Speech
- Samsung Tex to Speech engines

Answer (score 0):

Google text to speech's first stable release was sndroid 3.5.6, so I'll guess you'll better start on that version on minimum required android version

Don't know about samsung though :(

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I do not want TTS engine version. I want to know minimum android OS support from google TTS engine. Like android api level 8 or 15.

Answer (score 0):

Text to speech Engine requires the minimum api 4 references to:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/package-summary.html

Keep in mind that after api 4 a few features where added to tts

You can change the API levels on that website to see what was available on which level. You might gonna keep that site in mind for future projects, helped out very well so far, for me at least.

Comment: I have done the implementation with TTS. My problem is from which version of android Google TTS engine will be available. Example: I have a device running with android version 2.3.6 if open play store and searched for Google play store it is showing a message like "Your device is not compatible with this application" and i don't have install button available. I repeated the same step Samsung S5. It allowed me to download the Google TTS engine and working fine. So i need to know from which android version like 1.6 or 4.0 the Google TTS will support.